# Concurrently writing through Java sockets

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

This application initiates a new thread for each connection it receives, in this example, 2 clients (connections) tries to increment a variable 10 times each.

so at the end it should be 20, but instead its just 10.

**The Server listener:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1994);
            Socket socket=null;

                while (true) {
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                            new TestingSession(socket).start();

            }
        }
```

**Server's Thread ( session )**

```
class TestingSession extends Thread {
    private Socket socket;
    TestingSession(Socket socket) {  this.socket = socket;}
    public void run() {
                try {
                    DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            while (!socket.isClosed()) {

                dataOutputStream.writeInt(number.getI());
                int i = dataInputStream.readInt();
                number.setI(i);
                System.out.println(i);
```

**Clients main method :**

```
public class Run {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        UpdateTest t1 = new UpdateTest();
        UpdateTest t2 = new UpdateTest();
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        System.out.println("finished creation");

    }
}
```

**Clients Thread :**

```
public class UpdateTest extends Thread {

    public void run() {


        try {

            Socket socket;
            socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1994) ;
            for(int i=0; i <10;i++){

                int z=dataInputStream.readInt(); // read the static num
                dataOutputStream.writeInt(z+1); // write it incremented one
          }

            socket.close();


         }  catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

}
```

}

i want the variable to become 20, but instead it prints the following on the server side

**1
1
2
2
3
3
..
10
10**

Comment: Try running the two threads with a delay in between them. Use `Thread.sleep(1000)` for instance. It could be that both threads are constantly using the same numbers because they run faster than the ping of the packets.

This won't be the solution, but could be a good push in finding the solution.

Comment: What is `number`?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel sorry forgot to write that, just a class with a static memeber called I

Comment: And that is very important information, for one `number` is not a good name for a class (it doesn't meet the almost universal naming conventions for Java), `Number` would be more appropriate, but that would clash with `java.lang.Number`, so not a great name, but more importantly, this is shared state, which you must correctly synchronize when accessing concurrently, which is exactly your main problem. This is why posting a [mcve] is so important.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yea true i just made that class up to write this question, since the app is too long to post here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code you provided, it looks like you dont provide any synchronization to update and read number value. That's why you dont see 20 in the end. This code should be inside a synchronized block.

```
synchronized (number) {
    dataOutputStream.writeInt(number.getI());
    int i = dataInputStream.readInt();
    number.setI(i);`
}
```

Comment: The numbers sent by the client is incremented already. it reads the previous number (getI()) , adds one and sends it back

Comment: @user2962142 This answer is correct. Check the code. You're right that the value is incremented at the client side, but if two clients run concurrently they may both receive the same value (for instance 1) then both increment it (for instance to 2) and then both send the same value to the server.

Comment: @Mark that is a minor issue. I've edited the answer for miroh.

Comment: @ciamej that edit is syntactically correct, but very likely still wrong, if `number` is a global thing, then `synchronized (number)` would be more appropriate, but given the lack of a MCVE, that is just guessing.

Comment: Yes you are right, `this` would be different for two client threads. Synchronization should be on the same object.